# Swap text order using CSS

Tags: css

Let's assume I have a string that is, in HTML:

> Hello my name is Peter

I must use CSS to change it's order, to start from the right instead, so the output should be:

> Peter is name my Hello

I thought `directions: "rtl"` was the solution but it isn't.

Is this possible in CSS?

Comment: You could make an animation with `transfom`

Comment: It's not possible if the text is just by itself in a div. You could encapsulate each word in a span or something and use a reverse flex-box.

Comment: It is coming from an external device in a "month" space "day" format, and I need to show the day before the month.

Comment: But I have no control on how I get the string. It's in a div, that's it...

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to do what you want in pure css. `direction: "rtl"` will reorient the page so that text starts on the right, but if you are writing latin script, the characters will still read left to right.

I recommend javascript for this sort of task:

```
const el = document.querySelector('#YOUR_EMEMENT')
el.innerText = el.innerText.split(' ').reverse().join(' ')
```

Comment: do I replace #YOUR_EMEMENT with the css class I have for that div?

Comment: Yes, use `.YOUR_CLASS`

Comment: I should add that if this class is reused anywhere the querySelector will take the first instance, which might not be the one you want. If this is a commonly used class you  want to set an id on your div or at least build a longer css query that you know is unique.

Comment: I am no expert in javascript.

This is what I have:
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  const el = document.querySelector('.birthday_date')
  el.innerText = el.innerText.split(' ').reverse().join(' ')
});

However, it only swaps the first class of .birthday_date. Is there anything I could add so it loops it for ALL divs with that class? Not just the first one?

Comment: The snipped I posted is vanilla JS, and will run with no jQuery. If you want to do it the jQuery way, use this `$('.birthday_date').each(function(){this.innerText = this.innerText.split(' ').reverse().join(' ')})`. 

However, if what you posted is all you have, you probably don't need jQuery. If you want to do it the vanilla js way, do 
`const els = document.querySelectorAll('.birthday_date');
for(let el of els){el.innerText = el.innerText.split(' ').reverse().join(' ')}`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Unicode `&#x202b;` (**Right-to-Left Embedding**) for bidi text can control the current directionality of text.

```html
<span dir='rtl'>
  &#x202b;Hello &#x202b;my &#x202b;name &#x202b;is &#x202b;Peter
</span>
```

Comment: A good answer rely's on more than just code. You really should explain how this answers the question. Also this doesn't help in this case as the HTML is provided by an external source and is not modifiable.

Comment: Jon is correct. I can't use your solution as it's provided from an external source.